# May "posh" be used to modify people? -- "My mom is posh."

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Posh means attractive and expensive like a posh hotel.  I also read that you can say, 'My family is posh'.  If I will say, 'My mom is posh,' what does it mean?

Comment: It means that your name is either Brooklyn, Romeo, Cruz or Harper ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Posh doesn't really mean attractive. If anything, a posh person ***may*** actually come across as unattractive if they appear arrogant, or 'stuck-up'.

The word `posh` means `fancy`, `luxurious`, `elegant` and `high-class`. It's often associated with something that is 'better than what we're used to', and usually used by somebody looking **up** the social classes from below

`My mum is posh` can mean several things but it usually falls in to two categories:

- She could talk posh, which means she wouldn't use much slang, or informal words, usually speaking more proper. Although this is an extreme example, consider how the British royal family speak
- She may like posh things, for example, a posh restaurant might be an expensive one, where someone would go for a romantic meal and probably pay more money than they would elsewhere

Comment: Presumably she doesn't just like posh things, she's able to afford them - or already has them. Supposedly the British upper classes look down on people who buy, rather than inherit, their furniture.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think it is common to use 'posh' to define *a person*, by simple extrapolation one can deduce that a *posh person* is one who likes *posh things*, lives a *posh life*.